# Four + Five = Nine

Tags: mathematics, alphametic

Obviously, **FOUR + FIVE = NINE**, but what if each letter is assigned a digit (**0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9**), and two different letters can't be assigned the same digit?

Fill in numbers for the different letters to get the smallest value for **NINE** in this "equation":

```
  F O U R
+ F I V E
= N I N E
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there are multiple answers:

> 1980+1254=3234
> 1970+1264=3234
> 1960+1274=3234
> 1950+1284=3234

Comment: Care to show your logic to arrive at the numbers you did?

Comment: I used the same logic as Grant's answer.

Comment: @Duck there are 72 answers

Comment: @DEEM There are only 4 answers given the "smallest value of NINE" requirement, and they are the ones Duck provided.

Answer (score 17):

I also came to the answer:

> 3234

Reasoning:

> Starting from the least significant digit, as we are doing basic addition, we have $R + E = E$. That gives us our first known digit, $R = 0$. And we can fill in $E$ later as it won't effect anything else. 
>  The next thing to look at is the similar equation $O + I = I$. We have already used $0$, so the only way for this equation to become true is if it is actually $O + I + 1 = I$, with a carry from the previous column. We simplify this to be $O + 1 = 0$, or $O + 1 = 10$, and we now know that $O = 9$. 
>  From here we have two equations which equate to $N$. $1 + F + F = N$ and $U + V = N - 10$ (Due to it needing to carry a $1$). We can simply start filling in numbers to find a combination that holds true. If we set $F = 1$, then $N$ must be $3$, which then means $U + V = 13$, which can be accomplished with either $7 + 6$ or $8 + 5$. This leaves $2$ and $4$ free to be assigned to $E$ and $I$. We make $E = 2$ as it is the more significant digit, therefore gives the smaller total.

That brings us to the outcome that Duck has already provided:

> 1980+1254=3234
>  1970+1264=3234
>  1960+1274=3234
>  1950+1284=3234

Comment: I seem to have messed up my spoiler tags, and Im not sure how...but they are the same answers that other users have found

Comment: Those spoiler tags are a bit of a menace. I noticed yours pointed the wrong way and tried to fix them, but it didn’t work so I reverted the changes. Since the results are already known, consider just leaving them out in the open. You can use 2 spaces at the end of a line to force a line break, or just leave an empty line in between, or use the “-“ character at the start of each line to produce a bullet list.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Our answers are similar, but although I pipped you at the post (unknowingly!), I think yours was expressed more elegantly. +1 from me.

Comment: Nice explanation. I think the last sentence should say: "make I=2", not E.

Answer (score 3):

Logic:

> The smallest 4-digit number starts with digit 1. From the left-most column (col 1), $N \geq 2$, so let’s try $F=1$. 
>  Then $N = 2$ or $3$. 
>  Now, in col 4, since $R+E=E$ (or $10+E$), $R$ must be $0$ (or $10$, but that’s 2 digits). 
>  There is no carry to col 2. So $U+V=2$ doesn’t work ($0+2=2$, but $0$ has been taken). $U+V=12$ could work, but that would result in a carry to col 2. Since $O+I+1>I$, it must also have a carry to col 1, so $N>2$. No solution with $N=2$. 
>  Try $N=3$. We still have $R=0$ with no carry from col 4 to col 3. Col 3 is now $U+V=3$ or $13$. It must be $13$ since $0$ and $1$ have been taken. 
>  There being a carry from col 3 to col 2, $O=9$ so that $O+I+1=I+10$. 
>  The smallest value remaining for $I$ is $2$. 
>  So $U+V=13$ requires $5+8$ or $6+7$ or $7+6$ or $8+5$. Since $FOUR=19xx$ and $FIVE=12xx$, minimising them together (smallest product) requires $U=8, V=5$. Or if we want the smallest $max(FOUR,FIVE,NINE)$ we would have $U=5, V=8$. 
>  Either way, we have a free choice for $E$, the smallest value available being $E=4$.

Putting it all together, we have, depending on how we define ‘smallest’:

> 1980+1254=3234,
>  1950+1284=3234.

Answer (score 2):

If each digit represented like below.

> E = 5; F = 1; I = 2; N = 3; O = 9; R = 0; U = 6; V = 7

and

> E = 4; F = 1; I = 2; N = 3; O = 9; R = 0; U = 6; V = 7

Answers:

> `1 9 6 0 +`
> `1 2 7 5`
> `-------`
> `3 2 3 5`

and

> `1 9 6 0 +`
> `1 2 7 4`
> `-------`
> `3 2 3 4`

Comment: @CG. I got a smaller solution.

Comment: check it now, Probably I am more closer to smaller value.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin updated. I only got 3235

Comment: Consider (a) showing your work, and (b) putting the whole thing behind spoiler tags >!

Comment: I have a smaller solution. It is **very** close to yours.

Comment: @Duck you got 3234, nice work.

Comment: Yeah, you were really close!

Answer (score 1):

This puzzle has 72 solutions

> E=4 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=8 V=5 
>  E=6 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=8 V=5 
>  E=7 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=8 V=5 
>  E=4 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=7 V=6 
>  E=5 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=7 V=6 
>  E=8 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=7 V=6 
>  E=4 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=6 V=7 
>  E=5 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=6 V=7 
>  E=8 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=6 V=7 
>  E=4 F=1 I=2 N=3 O=9 R=0 U=5 V=8

AND ON AND ON

But the smallest solution is 3234 as @Duck has said